# Visual Studio file output error

Tags: c, eclipse, visual-studio-express

When I build the code bellow on eclipse everything works as expected on the command line and everything looks as it should be on the output file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for exit()
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *in, *out; // declare two FILE pointers
int ch;
// check for command-line arguments
if (argc < 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// set up input
if ((in = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "I couldn't open the file \"%s\"\n",
        argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// set up output
char *ptd;
ptd = (char*)malloc(150 * sizeof(char));
char x;
int i = 0;
while ((x = getchar()) != '\n'){
    ptd[i] = x;
    i++;
}
ptd[i + 1] = '\0';
strcat(ptd, ".txt"); // append .txt
if ((out = fopen(ptd, "w")) == NULL)
{ // open file for writing
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't create output file.\n");
    exit(3);
}
// copy data
while ((ch = getc(in)) != EOF)
        putc(ch, out); // print every 3rd char
// clean up
if (fclose(in) != 0 || fclose(out) != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in closing files\n");
free(ptd);
return 0;
}
```

but when I build it with visual studio, I get this thing "Í" after my file name 'till it reaches .txt and it uses all the allocated memory for the file name. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
while ((x = getchar()) != '\n'){
    ptd[i] = x;
    i++;               <=== increment, hence 'i' points to the char *after* the last one
}
ptd[i + 1] = '\0';     <== now you move *one char more* from the last one
strcat(ptd, ".txt"); // append .txt
```

here's how it works:

input string (from `getchar`)=`"abc\n"`

after `malloc` `ptd[]=<junk>`

after reading stdin `ptd[]="abc"<junk>`

after the while loop `i`==3 and points to the first byte of the rest of `<junk>`;

now `ptd[i+1]` which is `ptd[4]` is set to `0`

here's how ptd looks like: `ptd[]="abc"<junk char><zero>`

since `malloc` does not initialize memory to zeroes (`calloc` does) it just happened for you that  in GCC was zero and not zero in visual studio.

**Why?**

You still can reproduce this in eclipse as well.

before the line  `ptd = (char*)malloc(150 * sizeof(char));` add a loop to allocate from heap and fill in with garbage, to make `ptd` reuse that garbage.

```
char *p[20];
int n,j;
for(n=0;n<20;++n)
{
    p[n]=(char*)malloc(150 * sizeof(char));
    for(j=0;j<150;++j)
    {
        p[n][j]=(char)n*11+j+3;
    }
}

for(n=0;n<20;++n)
{
    free(p[n]);
}
```

What that means is (**probably**) a program compiled with GCC starts with clean heap, while MSVC starts with heap filled with garbage.

MSVC can do that when it fills heap with a garbage which helps detect the kind of human errors like the one you did.

Have a look at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx section "Find buffer overruns with debug heap":

> The debug heap also fills new memory blocks with a known value.
>
> Currently, the actual byte values used are as follows:
>
> New objects (0xCD)
>
> New objects are filled with 0xCD when they are allocated.

then, if you look here: http://www.idautomation.com/product-support/ascii-chart-char-set.html

you will see:

> Í     205     0xcd    0315    Í  PostScript (”) hungarumlaut

is the very character which you saw in your filename.

Comment: Thank you perfect answer, correct me If I am wrong but, this means eclipse uses memory for that "Í" character but I just can't see it right?

Comment: I just checked by making `ptd[i+1]` `ptd[i+3]` and eclipse just added random "h" to the file name.  Thanks again.

Comment: Í  is microsoft specific. It only used for debug heap in MSVC to detect errors. Otherwise it can be anything. no guarantees for the initial contents of the memory allocated with `malloc`.  The content of the newly allocated block of memory is not initialized, remaining with indeterminate values. You would have to initialize it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You are not terminating the string properly:

```
while ((x = getchar()) != '\n'){
    ptd[i] = x;
    i++;
}
ptd[i + 1] = '\0';
```

Here the `i` is incremented in the loop, such that the last `i` will be already past the built string. So the extra increment in the `ptd[i + 1] = '\0';` line will leave one character uninitialized. So the right code would be `ptd[i] = '\0';`

Comment: I am sure you are getting some junk there. Maybe accidentally it equals to zero, so you get the proper termination.

Comment: One more question, just because that junk thing made me confuse, let's say my file's name is abc.txt and it means name has 7 characters, so program shouldn't use other 143 allocated char spaces right? If so how can I check it?

Comment: Check what? You can use `strlen` to check the actual string length. Or if you want to use the memory in a less "wasteful" way, you can use dynamic allocation for the buffer. Since you are reading the string by single characters, you can `realloc` the buffer each time the character is read.

Comment: I meant the check that if it uses the rest of the space or not, but I think `strlen` gives me that answer. Thank you.